# Rails credentials rotation without restart server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, credentials, aws-secrets-manager

I'm currently implementing database credentials rotation. It's automatically managed by AWS SecretsManager
Problem is, when credentials are changed, Rails server still keeps the "old" ones.
Even if on the server, env variable are up to date since environment variables are loaded only once on startup of the Rails server.

It seems to be a pretty common usage to change credentials. How can we change them without restarting the Rails server?

After looking at [AWS Prescriptive Guidance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/rotate-database-credentials-without-restarting-containers.html) I was thinking to handle this directly on `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` but I'm afraid it's only for the fresh new connection I'm requesting at the time of this line and not across the entire app.

AWS idea makes sense to be but I'm asking community about this.

Important note, in my case, it is mandatory to **not restart** the Rails server.